# Data preparation for logistic regression

Tags: logistic, data-transformation

This figure:

[image: odds ratios]

shows my odds ratios. I believe they have to be linear for logistic regression to work and am wondering how to pre-process these data. Thanks.

Comment: Just for clarification, do the points at the 0.0 line really mean no observations within that category (from -30 to -15) or a very small odds ratio (same for the NA category at the rightmost of the plot)?

Comment: The observed values are in this range [-13.77 ... 36.56]. Sorry the -30...30 stems from the binning in R, which I tried for several predictors some of which go down to -30.

Comment: What do you intend to do with these data?  They look great for exploration, but for formal hypothesis testing your options will be limited.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Ultimately I would like to apply Bayesian Logistic Regression adjusted for presence-only data. See paper: Data Augmentation Approach in Bayesian Modelling of Presence-only Data. I am currently trying to get the naive Bayesian Logistic Regression to work whilst pre-processing the data correctly.

Comment: The non-monotonic behavior of log-odds - can it be explained by the sparse amount of data in the corresponding bins? In other words, what is the order of magnitude of data case counts contributing in the positive bins? The jump in the 24-27 bin looks like an indication of sparse data to me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data looks fine. Another reasonable way to show it on a plot (that connects to logistic regression) is to plot each binary outcome Y against its corresponding X. Then add a smoother (e.g.  `loess` in R, with `iter=0`) to see how the proportion with Y=1 varies with X.

Logistic regression does not require that the odds (or log odds) be linear in X; depending on what you want to do with the data, fitting a simple logistic regression of Y on X can tell you about an overall trend. Other options would be to regress Y on a spline representation of X. Or, yes, taking a Bayesian approach to a model in which the expectation of binary Y is logistic-linear in X, or some function of X - a.k.a. Bayesian logistic regression.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it has to be linear. I did lots of google searches and did not find anything really on data pre-processing for LR )-:. Can you apply LR to situations like this: ]-10 ... -5] the response variable is very likely to be zero, ]-5...5] the response variable is very likely to be one and ]5...10] the response variable is very likely to be zero?

Comment: Yes, you can use logistic regression in this situation. Using a spline might be a good idea here.

Comment: How? If I use a logit link function I cannot have low probabilities for low values (]-10 ... -5] ) and high values (]5...10]) but high probabilities for medium values (]-5...5])?!